# Dropped jwplayer, considering OpenVideoPlayer or Flowplayer

Tags: video

I have given up on Jwplayer as it will not even play a 25-second .3gp created 
on the latest version of Android running on an HTC EVO smartphone.

So I'm wondering if anyone has had reliably good experience with .3gp playback
using either of the other two players that seem recommended:

1)  **OVP, open video player**, at http://openvideoplayer.sourceforge.net/

-- OR --

2) **Flowplayer**, at http://flowplayer.org/

As a sanity check, before I started trying to develop with the jwplayer, I simply
tried playback of a .3gp video made on the highly-ubiquitous Android.  Jwplayer
failed that simple sanity check with a dispirited THUD, no way do I want to waste
time with a player that can't even do playback of one of the most common video formats.

Ultimately my users need to simply be able to upload a short video then see it played
back.  I'll need to add a few seconds of the company logo at the end of each uploaded video,
so I guess that means the player I used needs to have an API.

Comment: sheesh I may give up on open source video players altogether, nothing but crap out here looks like.  I tried these, the bottom line is (I think) you gotta buy one so that you'll get someone interested in supporting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't expect much luck obtaining a flash player that understands the 3gp format. You'll be better served using `ffmpeg` or some similar tool to convert the 3gp file into a mp4 file that flash can understand.

EDIT: ah, see [Is there a browser embedded player that can play 3gp, amr, mid, mp3 & wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322000/is-there-a-browser-embedded-player-that-can-play-3gp-amr-mid-mp3-wav). You will probably need to embed quicktime. The 3gp container format is not one that Flash natively handles.

Comment: Thanks man -- what got me going on jwplayer was their claim that their flash player supports 3gp but it actually does not, at least not a 3gp from a 2011-vintage Android smart phone (Evo).

Comment: Yeah, they definitely don't do the defacto 3gp container. I've used them for mp4 and they do quite well with that, but they are limited to the Flash player's supported formats and although http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html says they support the 3GPP format that says nothing about the container.